# zip Archive and download not working

Tags: php

I need to make a zip file in `index.php`.  My code is:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();

$DelFilePath="first.zip";

if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/admin/Allorders/".$DelFilePath)) {

        unlink ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/admin/Allorders/".$DelFilePath); 

}
if ($zip->open($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/admin/Allorders/".$DelFilePath, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) != TRUE) {
        die ("Could not open archive");
}
    $zip->addFile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/admin/index.php","file.php");

// close and save archive


$file=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/admin/Allorders/".$DelFilePath;

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"'); 
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
```

I get a 0 byte zip file.  What is the problem in my code?

Answer (score 2):

After you declare all the headers you need to echo the actual data out. So:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"'); 
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
echo $data;
```

Where $data is the content of your zip archive.

Also try a few var_dump() on the zip to see if it's OK in memory.

Comment: thanks @cen, can you tell me how to get data in $data variable ?, i mean hoe to use it, till i get 0 bite zip file

Comment: I have never used ZipArchive class before so I'm not sure. Perhaps ZipArchive::getStream in combination with stream_get_contents() function. See PHP documentation.